# Strpos not getting the correct result in condition

Tags: php, strpos

Hi Im having trouble trying to get it output towards the right condition, but right now its prompting into the else statement, instead of the the if statement, when I output the for each statement, it managed to output the files in the directory but I just cant get the string with matching filename even though the string matches it. My current output would be `here2`. When i checked for the output in `$res`, it would be empty.

```php
    if(strpos($var, "TL")!== false){
        foreach($dirIL as $file1){
            if(strpos( $file1 , $pattern) !== false){
                $res = $filePath .'IL\\' . $file1;
                return $res;
            } else{
                $fullPSPath = "PS File Not Found";
                //return $fullPSPath;
                return "here2"; //keeps returning this despite having a matching file name.
                }
            }
    } else {
        foreach($dirUL as $file2){
            if(strpos($file2, $pattern) !== false){                     
                $res = $filePath .'UL\\' . $file2;
                //return $res;
                return "here3";
            } else{
                $res = "PS File Not Found";
                //return $res;
                return "here4";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the problem. The code should be understandable and reproducible, contain sample data and not contain unknown functions.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that debugging should be possible even using `var_dump`

Comment: What is `$policyNo`?  What is `$PS_Path`?  We require a [mcve] in order to confidently help you and so that future researchers can determine if they are experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: I have edit the code so only the issue remains.